# Elevate an inner property's Keys as its own type definition

Tags: typescript

If I have some json such as

```
{
   "collection1" : {
       "key1" : { "value": "", "description" },
       "key2" : { "value": "", "description" } 
   },
   "collection2" : {
       "key1" : { "value": "", "description" },
       "key2" : { "value": "", "description" } 
   }
}
```

Where each collection will have the same set of keys.

And I pull this into my ts file with

`type collections = typeof import('./myjson.json')`

How would I go about elevating the keys from "collection1" so that I can have a new type derived from the imported json type?

I tried something like:

```
export type KeysOfType = {
    [P in collections["collection1"]]: { value: string, description: string }
}
```

But I am not sure of the syntax to extract out the keys from the child property.

Comment: you json isn't valid, I think. { value: "", "description" } where is the value of description?

Comment: Sorry I was just freehanding it.  I'll update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
type KeysofType = keyof collections["collection1"]
```

Comment: That did it.  I was able to use that with Record<> to get final type structure I was looking for.  Thanks